# When playing multiplayer, whose resources do you see?

Tags: genshin-impact

I was wondering: if I need to farm a particular resource (ores, flowers), and I've looted pretty much every instance of it on the map, can I join another player's world and get their instances of that resource?

So I want to know: when playing in another player's world, whose instances of resources are loaded? Can you get extra resources from taking the instances of another player online?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The resources visible are the one of the player host (who should be P1). You can take the resources of other players when you're in their world, the player taking the resource is the one getting them. In that regard, if you were to take resources from other world without asking, it would be stealing.

Source: [Genshin Impact Fandom wiki on co-op mode](https://genshin-impact.fandom.com/wiki/Co-Op_Mode#Rules_and_Restrictions)

Comment: But, if everybody is ok with it, you may take items from someone else's world.

Comment: There are also multiple achievements for collecting various plants or ores(?) in other players worlds. Also, you cannot open chests in other players worlds!